# Remove time from datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

I tried doing

```
        senddate.Value = Format(senddate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    sstartdate.Value = Format(sstartdate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    MsgBox(senddate.Value & " " & sstartdate.Value)
```

but the messagebox still returns the time as well. (message box is there for diagnostic purposes, though it also passes the time to the SQL string as well.)

I tried switching the date time pickers to custom format and it didn't work. Any ideas?

I need to turn it into a short, simple date so that I can input it into an SQL Access BETWEEN query

Comment: The DTP.Value property is a DateTime type which always has a Time value.  Use just the `.Date` portion in your query to omit the time.  BTW `Format(senddate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")` does nothing because Dates do not have a format, in fact that line probably means that Option Strict is Off because `Format` returns a string

Comment: Yes I have option strict off as it was throwing an error earlier, I forgot to turn it back on. thanks

Comment: Using ssenddate.date I get "date is not a member of system.windows.forms.datetimepicker"

where was I supposed to put the .date after?

Comment: `sstartdate.Value.Date`  Value is a `DateTime` type on the DTP, `.Date` is a property returning the Date only portion

Comment: using sstartdate.value.date It's still returning the time in the messagebox and the sql string, not sure what I am doing wrong. Anything else I should check?

Comment: `dt.Date.ToShortDateString` should chop off the time, I am not sure whether you are asking about a MsgBox, SQL or DateTimePicker at this point...or `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.  You can remove the time from the string result, but not the DTP.Value

Answer (score 0):

```
  senddate.Value = Format(senddate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    sstartdate.Value = Format(sstartdate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")

    MsgBox(senddate.Value & " " & sstartdate.Value).ToString
```

the month part should be in capital lettrs.